# Get The Text of a DropdownList from the generated ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, code-behind

This is my login page, assume that password and username is correct and get a certain data using session:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class OnlineAppSyss : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
        string teachersubjectlistquery = null;
        private DataSet teachersubjectlistData;
        private DataTable teacheraccountdetailsTable;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sendet, EventArgs e)
        {
            Teacher();
        }
        public void Teacher()
        {
            //Connection String
            connector.ConnectionString = "Data Source=keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True";

           //Subject List                  
           teachersubjectlistquery = "select distinct CourseNo from AssessmentForm where TeacherID =" + username + "";
           teachersubjectlistData = connector.ExecuteQuery(teachersubjectlistquery);
           teachersubjectlistTable = teachersubjectlistData.Tables[0];
           Session["TeacherSubjectList"] = teachersubjectlistTable;
         }
    }
```

I pass the DataTable "teachersubjectlistTable" in another page using Session.

In my Teacher Page, I declare dropdownlist to generate Items using the Session["TeacherSubjectList"].

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="SubjectList"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Its anchor tag to proceed to ValidateSubject Page:

```
<a class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top:-37px;margin-left:65px;" runat="server" onserverclick="TeacherSubjects_Click">Proceed</a>
```

and its code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MSSQLConnector;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class TeacherPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
        private DataSet SubjectlistData;
        private DataTable SubjectlistTable;
        string query = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Populate The Select Tag with Subjects
            SubjectList.DataSource = Session["TeacherSubjectList"];
            SubjectList.DataTextField = "CourseNo";
            SubjectList.DataValueField = "CourseNo";
            SubjectList.DataBind();
        }
        protected void TeacherSubjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string getText = SubjectList.SelectedItem.Text;
            //Connection String
            connector.ConnectionString = "Data Source=keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True";

            query = "select StudentID,CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = '" + getText + "'";

            SubjectlistData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);
            SubjectlistTable = SubjectlistData.Tables[0];

            //Add a colum check row
            SubjectlistTable.Columns.Add("Check", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));

            Session["ValidateSubject"] = SubjectlistTable;

            Response.Redirect("ValidateSubjectTeacher.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

in my another aspx page (ValidateSubject), I declare Gridview as holder of the Session:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" ID="ValidateSubject" Style="text-align: center"></asp:GridView>
```

and its aspx code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class ValidateSubjectTeacher : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateSubject.DataSource = Session["ValidateSubject"];
            ValidateSubject.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get the selected Item in my dropdownlist(TeacherPage) it will only get the data of the first item selected.

In my my dropdownlist(TeacherPage) two Items have been generated by the use of queries:

```
CmpE 515
CmpE 516
```

But when I select the "CmpE 516" Item and click proceed, the data displayed is only the "CmpE 515" Item. How do get the other items/values in my dropdownlist to display certain data if the user clicks a certain item?

This code here:

```
string getText = SubjectList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

it will only get the text 'CmpE 515' data even if I select the 'CmpE 516' and click proceed. How  do I get the other Items in my dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind the dropdown everytime the page loads, use `IsPostBack` property to check if the page loads the first time and only in that case bind your dropdown like this:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(!IsPostBack)
     { 
            //Populate The Select Tag with Subjects
            SubjectList.DataSource = Session["TeacherSubjectList"];
            SubjectList.DataTextField = "CourseNo";
            SubjectList.DataValueField = "CourseNo";
            SubjectList.DataBind();
     }
  }
```

Same applies to your `ValidateSubjectTeacher` page as well.

Comment: is it okay to add the if function in a click event button not in the page_load event?

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano - Didn't get you? A button click will anyways be a postback right? So doesn't make sense to check this property.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano - Great :) I hope you understood what was happening. When you don't use `IsPostBack` the dropdown was again populating and thus when you checked the selected item it was giving the first item because that was selected by default.

Comment: Yes thanks. :)  Honestly, I don't have enough knowledge in c# asp.net and its built in functions, I've been studying them while I make my code. :3

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano - That's fine. Keep learning :) You can accept the answer if this helped you.